# ValueError: could not convert string to float - but I'm not trying to insert a float

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to import string values into a dataframe using pandas but keep getting this error. What really confuses me is that the string is inserted perfectly fine for the first value in the loop, but once I get to the second input it seems to think I'm trying to insert floats. Not sure how to work around this.

Here's my code:

```
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
if filename.endswith('.docx'):
    print('Accessing: ' + filename)
    curr = di.getInfo(filename)
    c1 = di.c1
    insert = str(c1.station + ' ' + c1.date)

    df = pd.read_excel('Internal Master.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet4')

    i = df[df['MARKET'] == c1.market].index[0]
    df.at[i, c1.title] = insert
    print('Inserted ' + insert + ' at ' + c1.market + ',' + c1.title)
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\python\readWrite.py", line 18, in <module>
    df.at[i, c1.title] = str(insert)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2194, in __setitem__
    self.obj._set_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3033, in _set_value
    engine.set_value(series._values, index, value)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 96, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.set_value
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 109, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.set_value
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'WCPO 02/06/20'
```

Comment: At what line does this error appear? Can you post the entire message?

Comment: @desert_ranger Yeah! too long for the comment; adding to the question

Answer (score 0):

Hehe figured it out by setting the whole dataframe to string type thanks team